# Proving Infinite Turing Machine Language (with finite subset) is Recursively Enumerable

Tags: computability, turing-machines, semi-decidability

I'm trying to answer this question:

> Let $S$ be the strings $\langle P \rangle$ accepted by the Turing Machine $P$ with input alphabet $\{a,b\}$, where $P$ accepts an infinite number of strings beginning with $a$ and a finite number of strings beginning with $b$.
>
> 1. Is $P$ RE?
> 2. Is $P$ co-RE?

Comment: please don't erase a question this way. please restore it the way it was. If you wish to remove the question there should be a delete button (maybe you need more rep to see it)

Comment: @George, I rolled back the changes. You might want to post your answer as an actual answer (it's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question, and you also then get credit and rep for it!).

Comment: @LukeMathieson Take a look at the answer before making suggestions.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, the OP had removed his entire question, rendering it pointless from the site's perspective. My main purpose was to preserve a question (via a rollback) that others might find useful, and in doing so indicating to a new user what to do when they've answered their own question (i.e. put it in an answer not the question), it wasn't relevant what the content was, beyond not being offensive etc.

Comment: This screams for (the extended version of) Rice's theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first question, a reduction from the halting problem only shows that a problem is *hard*, not that it's *easy*. If the halting problem reduces to some problem $P$, then you know that $P$ isn't co-computably enumerable. So if you manage to reduce the halting problem to $L$, then this shows that $L$ is *not* co-computably enumerable. Perhaps that can inform your guess on the answer.

Regarding your second question, if you show that $L$ is c.e. but not computable, then indeed it follows directly that $L$ is not co-c.e. This is because a language that is both c.e. and co-c.e. is computable.

Let me give you a hint. Every Turing machine can be modified so that it accepts only strings beginning with 0: the new machine accepts $0x$ iff the old machine accepts $x$. Such a Turing machine belongs to $L$ iff it accepts infinitely many strings. Similarly, a machine which only accepts strings beginning with 1 belongs to $L$ iff it accepts finitely many strings.